# slf4j trace vs debug used with log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

From the log4j documentation I know that these are the levels in the h http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

TRACE,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR and
FATAL

Fatal being the top level. But could not understand the difference between Trace and  debug. I have tried with setting the log level to debug and I can see the trace messages. But when I set the log level to trace I cannot see the debug messages.

It means debug < trace ? Can any one confirm this please ?

Comment: Answered here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/360810/420649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRACE is the lowest level, under DEBUG.

Comment: why I cannot see the debug messages, when the log is set to trace ?

Comment: Misconfiguration, bug in log4j, who knows.

Comment: Have to verify, Thanks for the confirmation.